# Howto put xlmns="" in response

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have this response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <Response xmlns="http://blahblahblah">
         <SomeResult xmlns="">
            <id>16</id>
            <state>QUEQUE</state>
         </SomeResult>
      </Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And I nedd to know how to do this, from a wsdl:

```
<SomeResult xmlns="">
```

In the wsdl, I had this:

```
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
[...] xlmns:tns="http://blahblahblah" targetNamespace="http://blahblahblah">

<types>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
   targetNamespace="http://blahblahblah">

 [...]

 <operation name="TheOperation">
 <soap:operation soapAction="<anOperation>" style="document"/>
 <input><soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://blahblahblah"/></input>
 <output><soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://blahblahblah"/></output>
 </operation>

 [...]

 <xsd:complexType name="TheOperationResponseType">
    <xsd:all>
       <xsd:element name="Response" type="tns:Response" form="unqualified"/>
    </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>

 [...]

 <xsd:complexType name="Response">
   <xsd:all>
       <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
       <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

**The context:**

The boss give us the wsdl, but with that, I only can get responses like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <Response xmlns="http://blahblahblah">
         <SomeResult>
            <id>16</id>
            <state>QUEQUE</state>
         </SomeResult>
      </Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And.... the boss don't want to change his code to be consistent with the original wsd. :(, so I need  to know how to create a WSDL compatible with their real answer, and not the defined from the original WSDL.

The solutiont must be in the wsdl... language-independent (so, we cannot use something like Java annotations in our client code to make it compatible with the response... that was our first approach ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) say:

> The attribute value in a default namespace declaration MAY be empty.
>   This has the same effect, within the scope of the declaration, of
>   there being no default namespace.

So, if you want to get empty xmlns declaration in your response, you need to:

- setting the default namespace

  xmlns="your_namespace"
- and adjust SomeResult element to another namespace

---

In your WSDL you adjusted the default namespace and add following setting:

```
xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

This setting means the targetNamespace which you declared at the top of the schema only applies to elements in the schema compliant XML document. But you declared explicitly **unqualified** option to Response element.

```
<xsd:element name="Response" type="tns:Response" form="unqualified"/>
```

In this case the Response element get null namespace. Please check your soap response message without this setting.